# В webview не отображаются картинки из sd rкарты

Tags: android, webview

Здравствуйте. 
Скачиваю html файлы с сервера на карту, открываю файл

```
 webView.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/client/"+uri);
```

Текст открывается, картинки нет.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно потому, что в HTML-документе они, скорее всего, прописаны с указанием относительного пути:

```
<img src="image.jpg" … />
```

, но вы скачиваете лишь сам документ, без ресурсов, на которые он ссылается. Как следствие, при его открытии, `WebView` не может их найти.

Comment: нет, ресурсы тоже скачиваю, точно такие же пути и  на компьютере <img src="other/image.jpg" … />  и на компе и на сервере нормально открывается

Comment: даже попробовал редактировать на апарате файл и переместить файл в папку с картинками - результат тот же